# Can we reduce the startup time of SpringBoot by starting multiple threads

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a spring-boot service which is taking around 56 sec to start.
I would like to know if there is a possibility to reduce the application start-up time by configuring multiple threads for start-up process.

Thanks and regards,
Suraj Jannu

Answer (score 0):

By default, no. Spring Inits all of the beans on startup, to fail-fast, and not let the app be up (but not running). If you still would take the chance of runtime failures due to Init error of some beans later, only when needed, you can use Lazy loading: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/core/spring-bean-eager-vs-lazy-init